# Cómo insertar varias filas dependiendo del rango? App Script

Tags: script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Quisiera saber qué código puedo utilizar para copiar datos de una tabla a otra, sin embargo que en la tabla de destino se agreguen el número de filas necesarias para copiar los datos de la tabla de origen. Por ejemplo: si la tabla de origen tiene 6 filas, que se agreguen en la tabla de destino 6 filas en blanco y se peguen ahí estos datos.